# Project file contains ToolsVersion=“4.0” (old thread did not help)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project

I get this
Project file contains ToolsVersion=“4.0”, which is not supported by this version of MSBuild
when trying to build from VS2008 my setup project.  Now, I've edited all csproj files by replacing 4.0 with 3.5 to no avail!

Answer (score -1):

You can set current target framework to .net 4.0 in Nant by adding the following line to your nant script.

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.0" />
```

Comment: Excuse me, what exactly is Nant?